# Angular js datatable Use

Tags: angularjs, datatables

How can I turn basic table to datatable. My table code is here.
I add datatables.net module but I can't use it.

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="myTable">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Kategori ID</th>
  <th>Ürün ID</th>
  <th>Ürün Adı</th>
  <th>Ürün Hacmi</th>
  <th>Ürün Fiyatı</th>
  <th>Ürün Sayısı</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let item of products">
<td>{{item.productId}}</td>
<td>{{item.categoryId}}</td>
<td>{{item.productName}}</td>
<td>{{item.quantityPerUnit}}</td>
<td>{{item.unitPrice}}</td>
<td>{{item.unitsInStock}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: What do you mean by datatable here. You can use JQuery datatable to achieve it if you are working on angularJS. Otherwise use primeNG table if you are working on angular 2+.

Comment: Look at http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/welcome

Answer (score 0):

If you have added dependency of datatable then just add attribute in table tag

```
<table datatable="" class="table table-striped" id="myTable">
...
</table>
```

if dependency is not added then add it using

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['datatables']);
```

for more details go to http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/zeroConfig.